# Remove trailing slash from home link

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a project on a subfolder inside a subdomain directory.

Structure:

```
public_html
    subdomain
        subfolder
            .htaccess
        .htaccess
```

I redirect from `subdomain.domain.com` to `subdomain.domain.com/subfolder` using this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomain [R=301]
```

I moved `index.php` and `.htaccess` out of the `public` folder.

Here is `.htaccess` code inside `subfolder`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain.domain\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/subdomain.domain\.com" [R=301,L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

`web.php`:

```
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

When I visit `subdomain.domain.com/subfolder` it redirects to `subdomain.domain.com/subfolder/` but all other pages have no trailing slashes e.g. `subdomain.domain.com/subfolder/login` is working fine with no redirections with trailing slash.

How to fix this issue?